# How to import a module from outside the current folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to import a module from outside its directory in `a.py`.

The directory looks something like this:

```
.project
├── folder_1
│   └── a.py
|
├── folder_2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── b.py
```

My code in a.py

```
#contents of a.py
from ..folder_2 import b.py
```

But from this, I'm getting this error

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I've been searching for a solution for this problem for quite a while but I haven't been able to find anything that helps.

Comment: How about to add the path to `sys.path`?

Comment: im not entirely sure as to how to use `sys.path` but if youre able can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following structure:

```
├── project
├── __init__.py
├── folder_1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── a.py
├── folder_2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── b.py
└── main.py
```

your `a.py` will not complain when executing `main.py`:

```
from project.folder_1 import a
```

Since `project` is a package for `main.py` and `folder_1` and `folder_2` are subpackages of it, you can use
[Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references).

If you want to directly execute `a.py`, you can simply do the following:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('..')

from folder_2 import b
```